# How can I add my app's custom ringtones in res/raw folder to a ringtonepreference

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-preferences, ringtone

I have this RingtonePreference (from Android Studio's default SettingsActivity):

pref_notification.xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RingtonePreference
        android:dependency="notifications_alarm"
        android:key="notifications_alarm_ringtone"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_ringtone"
        android:ringtoneType="notification|all"
        android:defaultValue="content://settings/system/notification_sound" />
```

SettingsActivity.java:

```
private void setupSimplePreferencesScreen() {
    if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) {
        return;
    }

    // Add 'general' preferences.
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

    // Add 'notifications' preferences, and a corresponding header.
    PreferenceCategory fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_notifications);
    getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);

    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_alarm_ringtone"));
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);

        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_alarm_ringtone"));
    }
}
```

I would like to add my app's custom ringtones from res/raw folder to the list. (I don't need them to be available for other apps.)

Comment: I think you'll need to either create a custom Preference, or copy them to the device's shared storage (then they would be available to other apps too).

Comment: I don't want the ringtones in my app's res/raw folder to be available for other apps as ringtone (though it's not a problem if they are). I would like to show a list with the available ringtones + my custom ringtones. There should be a standard way to do this, because when I go to Android settings > Sound > Ringtone, then I see 5 apps as possible Intents. Some of them only show their custom ringtones, but other do show also other apps' ringtones.

Comment: So you can create a custom preference. There's a guide in the documentation site.

Comment: And if I will have my preference, then how can I pop up the intent picker for the "Ringtone Picker" action? I mean, I guess I'll need to add my custom preferencescreen to the Manifest, and filter it for this "ringtone picker" action, but what is it?

Comment: You don't need an intent filter, just use a custom preference instead of the RingtonePreference. See my answer.

Comment: I updated my answer to add another (imo better) option, to copy the files to the device storage.

Comment: See my class "ExtraRingtonePreference" at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31004356/909406

Comment: @almisoft, very nice! If you write this as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I made my own ExtraRingtonePreference based on this answer: [In preferences, select my sound just like with RingtonePreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792120/in-preferences-select-my-sound-just-like-with-ringtonepreference)

I'll include it here for future reference:

src/main/java/com/fletech/android/preference/ExtraRingtonePreference.java:

```
package com.fletech.android.preference;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import com.fletech.android.redalert.R;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class ExtraRingtonePreference extends DialogPreference {

    private Context mContext;
    private String mValue;
    private Ringtone ringtone;
    private int mRingtoneType;
    private boolean mShowSilent;
    private boolean mShowDefault;
    private CharSequence[] mExtraRingtones;
    private CharSequence[] mExtraRingtoneTitles;

    public ExtraRingtonePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);

        mContext = context;

        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ExtraRingtonePreference, 0, 0);

        mRingtoneType = a.getInt(R.styleable.ExtraRingtonePreference_ringtoneType, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        mShowDefault = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ExtraRingtonePreference_showDefault, true);
        mShowSilent = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ExtraRingtonePreference_showSilent, true);
        mExtraRingtones = a.getTextArray(R.styleable.ExtraRingtonePreference_extraRingtones);
        mExtraRingtoneTitles = a.getTextArray(R.styleable.ExtraRingtonePreference_extraRingtoneTitles);

        a.recycle();
    }

    public ExtraRingtonePreference(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return mValue;
    }

    private Map<String, Uri> getSounds(int type) {

        RingtoneManager ringtoneManager = new RingtoneManager(mContext);
        ringtoneManager.setType(type);
        Cursor cursor = ringtoneManager.getCursor();

        Map<String, Uri> list = new TreeMap<String, Uri>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String notificationTitle = cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX);
            Uri notificationUri = ringtoneManager.getRingtoneUri(cursor.getPosition());

            list.put(notificationTitle, notificationUri);
        }

        return list;
    }

    private Uri uriFromRaw(String name) {
        int resId = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "raw", mContext.getPackageName());
        return Uri.parse("android.resource://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/" + resId);
    }

    public String getExtraRingtoneTitle(CharSequence name) {
        if (mExtraRingtones != null && mExtraRingtoneTitles != null) {
            int index = Arrays.asList(mExtraRingtones).indexOf(name);
            return mExtraRingtoneTitles[index].toString();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getSummary() {

        String ringtoneTitle = null;

        if (mValue != null) {

            if (mValue.length() == 0)
                ringtoneTitle = mContext.getString(R.string.silent);

            Uri mValueUri = Uri.parse(mValue);
            if (ringtoneTitle == null && mExtraRingtones != null && mExtraRingtoneTitles != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < mExtraRingtones.length; i++) {
                    Uri uriExtra = uriFromRaw(mExtraRingtones[i].toString());
                    if (uriExtra.equals(mValueUri)) {
                        ringtoneTitle = mExtraRingtoneTitles[i].toString();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (ringtoneTitle == null) {
                Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, mValueUri);
                if (ringtone != null) {
                    String title = ringtone.getTitle(mContext);
                    if (title != null && title.length() > 0) {
                        ringtoneTitle = title;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        CharSequence summary = super.getSummary();

        if (ringtoneTitle != null) {
//            if (summary != null)
//                return String.format(summary.toString(), ringtoneTitle);
//            else
                return ringtoneTitle;
        } else return summary;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) {

        final Map<String, Uri> sounds = new LinkedHashMap<String, Uri>();

        if (mExtraRingtones != null) {
            for (CharSequence extraRingtone : mExtraRingtones) {
                Uri uri = uriFromRaw(extraRingtone.toString());
                String title = getExtraRingtoneTitle(extraRingtone);

                sounds.put(title, uri);
            }
        }

        if (mShowSilent)
            sounds.put(mContext.getString(R.string.silent), Uri.parse(""));

        if (mShowDefault) {
            Uri uriDefault = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(mRingtoneType);
            if (uriDefault != null) {
                Ringtone ringtoneDefault = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, uriDefault);
                if (ringtoneDefault != null) {
                    sounds.put(ringtoneDefault.getTitle(mContext), uriDefault);
                }
            }
        }

        sounds.putAll(getSounds(mRingtoneType));

        final String[] titleArray = sounds.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
        final Uri[] uriArray = sounds.values().toArray(new Uri[0]);

        int index = mValue != null ? Arrays.asList(uriArray).indexOf(Uri.parse(mValue)) : -1;

        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(titleArray, index, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                if (ringtone != null)
                    ringtone.stop();

                Uri uri = uriArray[which];

                if (uri != null) {
                    if (uri.toString().length() > 0) {
                        ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, uri);
                        if (ringtone != null) {
                            ringtone.play();
                        }
                    }
                    mValue = uri.toString();
                } else mValue = null;

            }
        });

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_save, this);
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel, this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {

        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

        if (ringtone != null)
            ringtone.stop();

        if (positiveResult && callChangeListener(mValue)) {
            persistString(mValue);
            notifyChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        return a.getString(index);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
        if (restoreValue) {
            mValue = getPersistedString("");
        } else {
            if (mExtraRingtones != null && defaultValue != null && defaultValue.toString().length() > 0) {

                int index = Arrays.asList(mExtraRingtones).indexOf((CharSequence) defaultValue);
                if (index >= 0) {
                    mValue = uriFromRaw(defaultValue.toString()).toString();
                } else {
                    mValue = (String)defaultValue;
                }

            } else {
                mValue = (String)defaultValue;
            }

            persistString(mValue);
        }
    }
}
```

src/main/res/values.attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ExtraRingtonePreference">
        <attr name="ringtoneType"><!-- Should correspond to RingtoneManager -->
            <!-- TYPE_RINGTONE: Ringtones. -->
            <flag name="ringtone" value="1" />
            <!-- TYPE_NOTIFICATION: Notification sounds. -->
            <flag name="notification" value="2" />
            <!-- TYPE_ALARM: Alarm sounds. -->
            <flag name="alarm" value="4" />
            <!-- TYPE_ALL: All available ringtone sounds. -->
            <flag name="all" value="7" />
        </attr>
        <attr name="showSilent" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="showDefault" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="extraRingtones" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="extraRingtoneTitles" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

src/res/values/ringtone_preference_strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="ringtone_title">Ringtone</string>
    <string name="silent">Silent</string>
    <string name="dialog_save">Save</string>
    <string name="dialog_cancel">Cancel</string>

    <string-array name="extra_ringtones">
        <item>beep</item>
        <item>beep_beep</item>
        <item>default</item>
        <item>test</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="extra_ringtone_titles">
        <item>Beep</item>
        <item>Beep-Beep</item>
        <item>Default</item>
        <item>Test</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

and the usage in src/main/res/xml/pref_alarm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:auto="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <com.fletech.android.preference.ExtraRingtonePreference
        android:key="notifications_alarm_ringtone"
        android:title="@string/ringtone_title"
        android:defaultValue="default"
        auto:ringtoneType="alarm"
        auto:showSilent="true"
        auto:showDefault="true"
        auto:extraRingtones="@array/extra_ringtones"
        auto:extraRingtoneTitles="@array/extra_ringtone_titles"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1: Copy to device storage**

Copy your ringtone files to the device's storage. I did basically this for an app on GitHub, [here](https://github.com/szh/breakify/blob/86e4a8cc28441229d90e59153ed5988b14f06e23/app/src/main/java/com/heightechllc/breakify/CustomAlarmTones.java), where I copied alarm tones from raw resources to the device's alarms directory (you'll need to replace all the instances of "alarms" with "ringtones"). Then we use `ContentValues` to create metadata telling the system that the files are ringtones and use `MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath` and then `context.getContentResolver().insert(contentUri, contentValues)` to add the ringtones to the device's database, so they'll be included in the `RingtonePreference`'s list.
You can also set a ringtone as the default using `RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri()`, though you'll need the `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission.

Also, remember to use the URI you get from `getContentUriForPath()` when calling `getContentResolver().insert()` and `RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri()`.
And, make sure you add to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Option 2: Custom preference**

Create a custom preference, as shown in [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Custom), or you can use (or subclass) the [ListPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html). You will need to retrieve all the device's ringtones using `RingtoneManager.getCursor()` ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#getCursor())) and add them to the list, and include your custom ringtones also.

Then, in your preferences.xml file, instead of RingtonePreference, you would use

```
<com.yourapp.CustomPreference android:key="your_key"
    ...
```

---

In your case, since it's okay if other apps have access to the ringtones as well, I'd recommend using the first method, since in general I feel it's better not to duplicate functionality already provided by the system, since it's best to utilize what the user is already familiar with.